# I can't install gems with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm new to ruby version manager and when i tried to install rails after installing it, I get this error . I tried to search other SO questions as well but didn't want to re-install ruby version manager. Even though when I try sudo for installation, it doesn't work.

The error I get is as follows:"ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/sunil/.gem/specs"

Comment: Though it should not be needed normally, but try using `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

1. `ls -ld /home/sunil/.gem/specs` to check that folder permissions.
2. `whoami` to compare current user with `/home/sunil/.gem/specs` permissions
3. Maybe `chown -R sunil:sunil ~/.gem` to change owner in case .gem directory is not owned by sunil.
4. Maybe `chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w ~/.gem` to [change permissions](https://superuser.com/a/91966/145603).

Comment: it says i don't have spec directory. I don't have permission to create spec folder. so I got stuck in the first step.

ls -ld /home/sunil/.gem/specs
ls: cannot access /home/sunil/.gem/specs: No such file or directory

Comment: And I tried adding spec folder as well but no luck. Is changing the permission only thing required to get things done? I got this error afterwards:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/sunil/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%44